# How To Construct This Query To Replace A Row With A Matching Element

Tags: php, mysql

So, my objective here is to send the user id as well as the current date of the login to the server. Here's an image of my results.

[image: stuff]

Now here is the code I'm using:

```
$command = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `userStats`(`UserId`, `LastLogin`) VALUES($userId, CURDATE())";
mysqli_query($con,$command);
```

I want the command to automatically update the last login date of the row with the same UserId. How can I go about doing this? I'm completely new to MySQL.

Comment: `UPDATE \`LastLogin\` WHERE \`UserId\` = $UserId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken about what you want, possibly yo need [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) or [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
REPLACE INTO `userStats`(`UserId`, `LastLogin`) VALUES($userId, CURDATE());
```

by this query, your userid will not be double exist if it is Prim key or Unique;

or simpy this:

```
UPDATE `userStats` SET `LastLogin` = CURDATE() WHERE `UserId` = $userId;
```

good luck !!